# Docusign workspace creation error

Tags: rest, docusignapi

I am trying to create a workspace using below code. but I am getting this error.

"errorCode": "ACCOUNT_LACKS_PERMISSIONS",

"message": "This Account lacks sufficient permissions. Account level AllowWorkspaceCreate permission is required. WorkspaceId = 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000".

```
        WorkspacesApi workspaces = new WorkspacesApi(Configuration.Default);

        Workspace item = new Workspace();

        var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        WorkspaceUser user = new WorkspaceUser
        {

            Email = "test@gmail.com",
            Type = "CompanyUser",
            UserName = "test",
            UserId = "76986fe6-5ac9-4b2c-8d68-891000122939",
            WorkspaceId = guid

        };
        item.BillableAccountId = "AccountId";
        item.WorkspaceId = guid;
        item.WorkspaceDescription = "Testing workspace";
        item.BillableAccountId = accountId;
        item.Created = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        item.CreatedByInformation = user;
        item.LastModifiedByInformation = user;
        item.Status = null;
        item.WorkspaceName = "Test work";
        var result = workspaces.CreateWorkspace(accountId, item);
```

I have tried multiple options to change AllowWorkspaceCreate to true but I am not able to change the account settings. I have tried to update using Rest API and API explore. the result is same and the flag does not update to true.
is there any way I can change this setting. 
Please refer below code where I am trying to update the flag using rest API.

```
        AccountsApi api = new AccountsApi(Configuration.Default);

        ErrorDetails error = new ErrorDetails();

        NameValue namevalue = new NameValue
        {
            ErrorDetails = error,
            Name = "allowWorkspaceCreate",
            OriginalValue = "false",
            Value = "true"
        };


        List<NameValue> nm = new List<NameValue> { namevalue };

        AccountSettingsInformation accountSettings = new AccountSettingsInformation(nm);

        api.UpdateSettings(accountId, accountSettings);

        var listsettings = api.ListSettings(accountId);
```

There is no issue while executing the rest API update settings method.
I have used API explorer to update the flag without any success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a DocuSign backend settings ("`Allow Rooms Create`") which needs to be enabled in your account by someone in DocuSign, you cannot enable it using API. Please contact your `DocuSign Account manager` to enable this setting from the backend.

Comment: Thanks, we have approached docu sign team to help on this.

Comment: thanks, now i am able to create work space after enabling this back end setting.